# How to check Validity of an URL

Tags: android, string, url, browser

I am working on a web Browser, I have a `SearchView` in it, for user to input queries. I want to differentiate between a search query or a web address. My current code just add `http://www.` in front of any query that comes in and try to load it.

This is my current code.

```
String query = search_q;

        if(!query.startsWith("www.")&& !query.startsWith("http://")){ 
            query = "www."+ query ;
        }

        if(!query.startsWith("http://")){
            query = "http://"+query;
        }

        if( Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(query).matches()){  //checks if the query looks like an URL
            web1.loadUrl(query);
        }
        else
        web1.loadUrl("https://www.google.com//search?q=+"+search_q);
```

The problem is that `Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(query).matches()` returns true even if `http://www.abc` is passed into it.

Answer (score 1):

check

```
if( Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(query).matches() && isUrl(query)){  //checks if the query looks like an URL
        web1.loadUrl(query);
    }
```

function defintion **isUrl**:-

```
    public  Boolean isUrl(String query){

    int a=0;
    int onlyfind=0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i<query.length() ; i++){

        if (query.charAt(i) == '.')
            a++;
        if(a==1){

            onlyfind= i;
        }
    }

    if(a==1){

        if(query.substring(0,onlyfind+1).equals("http://www"))
            return  false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: try substring(0,onlyfind)

Comment: hope you get the idea what am trying to do here and tweak some code rather copy-paste blindly!

Answer (score 0):

Try validating the url(query) using this method:

```
//isValidURL(query);
boolean isValidURL(String url) {
  try {
    new URI(url).parseServerAuthority();
    return true;
  } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

If it returns `false`, then:

```
web1.loadUrl("https://www.google.com//search?q=+"+search_q);
```

Comment: App is still acting same way.

Comment: I added your function definition, and swapped the `Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(query).matches()` in my last `if` with `isValidURL(query)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to validate URL is using regex. Because if you are working on a browser, you should not limit the validation of string queries that starts with `www`, what if the website is `dev.website.com`? it is a valid website URL, or what if the address starts with `https` and not just `http`?. So I think Try using regex to have a reference pattern in validating if the query string is URL or not:

```
private boolean isURL(CharSequence searchQuery) {
    Pattern urlPattern = Pattern.compile("(https?:\\/\\/(?:www\\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.[^\\s]{2,}|www\\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.[^\\w\\D\\S]{2,}|[^\\s]{2,}[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.[^\\s]{2,})");
    Matcher matcher = urlPattern.matcher(searchQuery);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

Then call that method:

```
String query = search_q;
if(isURL(query)) {
     web1.loadUrl(query);
} else {
    web1.loadUrl("https://www.google.com//search?q=+"+search_q);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am getting two errors in your code, In first line of `isURL` body `illegal escape character in string literal` and the second error is in very next line, it says `method call expected`.